# OpenCV - Camera calibration - Units of x and y

Tags: python, opencv, distortion

The camera calibration in OpenCV gives a quantitative representation of the distortion of the imaging system. For example, radial distortion can be determined by the coefficients k1, k2, k3, ... . The original position of a pixel (x,y) gets shifted to the distorted position (x_distorted, y_distorted) by the following equations [1]:

```
x_{distorted} = x (1+k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6  + ...)
y_{distorted} = y (1+k_1 r^2 + k_2 r^4 + k_3 r^6  + ...)
```

here, r is the distance from the center.
Using OpenCV [1] I am able to get the coefficients.
However, I am wondering about the units of the coefficients.

Clearly, I can not just calculate x,y and r in units of pixel.
I did that, this gives my values which are **12 orders of magnitude off (!!!)**

I suppose they are somewhat normalized.
Where do I find the documentation on the normalization of the value?

[1] https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html

I wanted to estimate the difference in x to x_distorted in units of pixel.
For a very slightly distorted image (e.g. I would expect a difference of less than 5 pixel), I got a difference using the equations above of ~1*10^12.

```
def distortion_delta(img, center, dist):
    k1, k2, p1, p2, k3 = dist
    #radial distortion
    distorted_x = np.zeros_like(img)
    distorted_y = np.zeros_like(img)
    xc, yc = center
    h, w = np.shape(img)
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            r = np.sqrt((i-xc)**2+(j-yc)**2)
            distorted_x[i,j] = (i-xc)*(1+ k1*r**2 + k2*r**4+ k3*r**6)
            distorted_y[i,j] = (j-yc)*(1+ k1*r**2 + k2*r**4+ k3*r**6)
    return distorted_x, distorted_y

dist = [-1.21094023e+01,  5.08189016e+02,  1.21622025e-01, -2.98076561e-03, 1.13290212e+00]

img = np.ones((50, 100))
dx, dy = distortion_delta(img, [25,50], dist)
```

Comment: You could look at the opencv source code (it is open source!).

Comment: Units of `x` and `x_distroted` are not pixel.  Perhaps, scale factors( `fx`, `fy` ) is what you are finding? See "Detailed Description" of https://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html

Comment: @Micka: I did. But I cannot find anything about this in the source code. I am sure that it is somewhere.

Comment: @fana: In this document x and x_distorted are normalized to z, which the output of the function does not provide.

Comment: z? Maybe x and y are normalzed to camera coordinate system. I think then the center is the principal point (3rd column in the camera matrix) and pixels are in the x/y range of [-1, 1] around that center.

Comment: I think x/y is not limited to [-1,1]. (If so, max horizontal/vertical fov is limited to 90degree)

Comment: x/y is considered as the position (X,Y,Z) projected onto the plane(z=1) on camera coordinate system. (not on the pixel_image yet)
So, if you are calculating difference between `x` and `x_distorted` **on this plane**, unit of the amount is not pixel.

Comment: @fana: But what is it? It can't be just random numbers! It should be possible to convert everything into pixel or at least some meaningful quantities

Comment: This z=1 plane is... it could be called as a virtual light-receiving surface (sensor array) ?
Position on this plane is related to pixel position of camera image. This relationship is modeled with {cx,cy,fx,fy}.

Comment: @fana: I compared every suggested solution to a calculation of the grid point differences from a perfect grid (without distortion) and with some added distortion. All suggested solutions are at least 2 orders of magnitude off!